# check whether selected text clicked or not

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a div element with text inside. I want to know what the user clicked on, selected text or not selected  ? The main goal to distinguish between selected text clicking and unselected text clicking

Comment: Can you show us the code? HTML and JS of what you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you throw this useful piece of CSS on the div in order to make the text non-selectable:

```
div {
    user-select: none;
}
```

Change the div to the correct class or ID, but that will make the text non-selectable so that you can tell that they have only clicked it. I use this for almost everything that I have that is clickable.

Answer (score 1):

This will run 2 different functions. When you click on the selected text, it will run one function, making the background red, and when you click on the non-selected text, it will run another function, making the background green. Hope this hepls.

```js
function red(){

//this function will be executed when the selected text is clicked

document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
function green(){

/*this function will be executed when the non-selected text is clicked*/

document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```css
body{
font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div><span onclick="red()" style="background-color:yellow">this text is selected</span>,<span onclick="green()"> this text is not</span></div>
</body>
```

Comment: sorry , i meant selected by mouse  , not having the separate span

Comment: then I guess i don't understand your question, you have a div with text inside it, and you want to know what text they clicked on correct? Usually to run a function when a element is clicked, you need to have something to click on, that is what the 2 spans were for. Could you maybe restate your question or show what code you tried so I can get a better idea of your question?

Comment: there is one span , with a text "Hello word".  User can select any symbol . I wanna know if user clicked on selection area or out of selection area

Comment: I am sorry, I guess I misunderstood your question. I am sorry I don't have an answer for you right now. Just some friendly advice, when you ask a question, it is helpful to attach some code or a little more detailed definition that way people trying to answer have more of a base to work off of. Sorry I misunderstood the question, I will you the best of luck with your problem.